# Python - occurrence of substring in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with a function that would search for a substring in a list of lists, as the first three characters of each item in the list.  For example, if the substring is `'aaa'` and the list of lists is `[['aaa111', 'aba123', 'aaa123'], ['aaa302', 'cad222']]`, I would like the function to return a list of percentages `[66, 50]`, since `'aaa'` appears in the first list 2/3 times, and in the second list 1/2 times.  So far I have:

```
def percentage(list_of_lists, substring):
    count = 0
    percentage = []
    for item in list_of_lists:
        for i in item:
            if substring == i[0:3]:
                count += 1
        percentage.append(int(count / len(item) * 100))
    return percentage
```

I understand that my code may be excessive, but I'm just getting the gist of Python so I'm not worried.

```
>>> percentage([['aaa111', 'aba123', 'aaa123'], ['aaa302', 'cad222']], 'aaa')
[66, 150]
```

How do I make it count list by list in my list_of_lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things...

1. Reset your `count` for each loop
2. Use float for division (only for python 2.x)

I changed the `count` -> `0.0`

```
def percentage(list_of_lists, substring):
    percentage = []
    for item in list_of_lists:
        count = 0.0
        for i in item:
            if substring == i[0:3]:
                count += 1
        percentage.append(int(count / len(item) * 100))
    return percentage

# Test
In [17]: l = [['aaa111', 'aba123', 'aaa123'], ['aaa302', 'cad222']]
In [18]: s = 'aaa'
In [19]: percentage(l,s)
Out[19]: [66, 50]
```

Comment: It's always easier than I expect... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ya. It's fun when it's just a single line to adjust :-)

Comment: Would be better to use `i.startswith(substring)` instead of `substring == i[0:3]:` in case the substring length changes.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `lambda` and `map` function :

```
>>> [(sum(map(lambda z: "aaa" in z,z))*100/len(z)) for z in [y for y in [['aaa111', 'aba123', 'aaa123'], ['aaa302', 'cad222']]]]
[66, 50]
```

Answer (score 1):

This modified code works for me:

```
def percentage(list_of_lists, substring):
    count = 0
    percentage = []
    for item in list_of_lists:
        for i in item:
            if substring == i[0:3]:
                count += 1
        percentage.append(int(count / len(item) * 100))
        count = 0
    return percentage
```